# snap creating folders in the /home/user on English

Tags: directory, snap, language-support

I have this bug that, when opening a snap, duplicated folders on English are created. This issue has happened to me on 16.04 and 17.10 on two different computers, but I can't find any information about it.

Where should I open a bug?

It happends with diferents snaps. Thank you :)

Comment: A bug has [already been filed](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1746710). Please feel free to state that it affects you too and add a comment if there is something you think the bug reporter missed.

Comment: It would be useful for anyone affected to try 18.04 dev & see if still an issue. (- 18.04  dev will get bug fixes, 17.10 not so much. If it required an SRU in 17.10 then generally it has to have been fixed in 18.04 dev first

Comment: I have the same problem on 16.04.3

Comment: The Problem also exists on 18.04 after a fresh/clean install.