# Spotify snaps new folders?

Tags: 16.04, software-center, snap

I installed Telegram and Spotify via the Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 16.04
Now I have in my personal folder (where all the folders like desktop, pictures,  etc. are) duplicates of those folders along with a snap folder.

Where do they come from?
Can I delete them without breaking snap?

```
du -hl --max-depth 1 ~/ | sort -k2 -t/ 

du: das Verzeichnis '/home/bernhard/.cache/dconf' kann nicht gelesen werden: Keine Berechtigung
du: das Verzeichnis '/home/bernhard/.dbus' kann nicht gelesen werden: Keine Berechtigung
38G /home/bernhard/
222M    /home/bernhard/Bilder
266M    /home/bernhard/.cache
20M /home/bernhard/.cliqz
56K /home/bernhard/.compiz
9,5M    /home/bernhard/.config
4,0K    /home/bernhard/.dbus
4,0K    /home/bernhard/Desktop
4,0K    /home/bernhard/Documents
4,6G    /home/bernhard/Dokumente
6,7M    /home/bernhard/Downloads
23M /home/bernhard/.dropbox
4,0G    /home/bernhard/Dropbox
213M    /home/bernhard/.dropbox-dist
24K /home/bernhard/.gconf
24K /home/bernhard/.gnome
8,0K    /home/bernhard/.gnupg
24G /home/bernhard/.local
28K /home/bernhard/.macromedia
28M /home/bernhard/.mozilla
4,0K    /home/bernhard/Music
4,0K    /home/bernhard/Musik
4,0K    /home/bernhard/Öffentlich
4,0K    /home/bernhard/Pictures
36K /home/bernhard/.pki
4,0K    /home/bernhard/Public
3,9G    /home/bernhard/Schreibtisch
42M /home/bernhard/snap
4,0K    /home/bernhard/Templates
1,1G    /home/bernhard/.thunderbird
4,0K    /home/bernhard/Videos
4,0K    /home/bernhard/Vorlagen
```

This might be a duplicate:

[snap creating folders in the /home/user on English](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002179/snap-creating-folders-in-the-home-user-on-english)

Comment: could you edit your post and paste the output of this `du -hl  --max-depth 1 ~/ | sort  -k2 -t/`